# 'No such device or address' returned from FirebaseAdmin SDK on .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am sending push notifications to devices from Firebase cloud messaging service. For doing so I used FirebaseAdmin SDK on .Net Core. I have followed the exact instructions from Firebase documentation to initialize FirebaseApp and send messages. Since this code needed to run from behind a firewall, i was given a tested proxy server from our infra team to set on Firebase admin's HttpClientFactory which i therefore implemented to serve the purpose.
Here's my code...

**Init part**

```
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
{
    Credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson("")// service account json content,
    HttpClientFactory = new ProxyHttpClientFactory(new WebProxy()
    {
        Address = new Uri("") //anonymous proxy address
    })
});
```

**HttpClientFactory Implementation**

```
public sealed class ProxyHttpClientFactory : HttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly IWebProxy _proxy;
    public ProxyHttpClientFactory(IWebProxy proxy)
    {
        _proxy = proxy;
    }

    protected override HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = _proxy,
            UseProxy = true,
        };
    }
}
```

**Sending the Firebase Message**

```
var _fcm = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance;

var message = new Message()
{
    Notification = new Notification()
    {
        Title = "title",
        Body = "body"
    },
    Token = "" //valid device token
};

_fcm.SendAsync(message);
```

Upon calling the SendAsync from FCM i will receive an http exception saying:
'No such device or address'
Which most probably means the proxy has not worked as expected and i am still stuck behind the Firewall. I have managed to send message via proxy from Curl command but cannot seem to make it work from dot net side. I have tampered with `WebProxy` properties, sending empty credentials, enabling and disabling proxy for local, sending null for baypass list, etc, all to no avail. Service account content is fine and is being set as it should, even proxy settings in client factory seems to be in place but not working.

Any workaround/solutions would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after trying out almost everything finally got to fix this problem by passing the proxy-enabled HttpClientFactory to GoogleCredentials as well. Apparently setting the HttpClientFactory on Firebase options is not enough, which is an obvious bug in FirebaseAdmin in my opinion. Anyhow, this is how I patched the thing:

```
ServiceAccountCredential serviceAccountCredential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer("---client email---")
{
    ProjectId = "---project id----",
    HttpClientFactory = new ProxyHttpClientFactory(new WebProxy()
    {
        Address = new Uri("---anonymous proxy address---")
    })
}.FromPrivateKey("---private key---"));

GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromServiceAccountCredential(serviceAccountCredential);
```

`ServiceAccountCredential` is the underlying type for `GoogleCredentials` type. Firebase admin will take care of composing this from the high-level GoogleCredentials property. Yet in this special case, it wouldn't inject the `HttpClientFactory` to the credentials, causing the code not to be able to reach the token endpoint.

So yes, the cooked `GoogleCredentials` object will later be passed to FirebaseApp's `Create` method.